# NIntegrate and Integrate of a Spherical Bessel function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to integrate a spherical Bessel function. I have used both the `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` functions in *Mathematica* but the values given by each do not match. Any reason why this happens?

```
NIntegrate[((BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1]*r]))^2*r, {r, 0, a}]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::ncvb: "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive
> bisections in r near {r} = {3.13053*10^-59}. NIntegrate obtained
> 1.81126695652224073244637134881619178279603605269044825189376376942`65.954589770191*^2647
> and 1.7853272819936654408129572054378095060361571646917142221312888537`65.954589770191*^2647
> for the integral and error estimates."
> ```

```
1.811266956522241*10^2647

Integrate[((BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1]*r]))^2*r, {r, 0, a}]
0.
```

Edit:
I forgot to mention $a=0.02$. I also noticed that the below integral should converge as I do not see any singularities but I'm not too familiar with spherical Bessel functions.

```
Integrate[((BesselJ[15/2, 0.0000001*r]))^2*r, {r, 0, a}]
```

> ```
> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of
> ((-1.35135*10^47\r+1.7325*10^32\r^3-<<22>>\<<1>>+r^7)\<<1>>+<<1>>)^2/r^14 does not
> converge on {0,0.02`}."
> ```

```
                   6                          -7
Integrate[6.3662 10  Power[Cos[12.5664 - 1. 10   r] - 

               47                    -7               32                    -7
     1.35135 10   Cos[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]   1.7325 10   Cos[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]
     ------------------------------------- + ------------------------------------ - 
                       6                                       4
                      r                                       r

            16                    -7                54                    -7
     3.78 10   Cos[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]   1.35135 10   Sin[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]
     ---------------------------------- - ------------------------------------- + 
                      2                                     7
                     r                                     r

             39                    -7             24                    -7
     6.237 10   Sin[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]   3.15 10   Sin[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]
     ----------------------------------- - ---------------------------------- + 
                      5                                     3
                     r                                     r

           8                    -7
     2.8 10  Sin[12.5664 - 1. 10   r]
     --------------------------------, 2], {r, 0, 0.02}]
                    r
```

Comment: Please copy your output as `InputForm` (in the context menu).

Answer (score 5):

Expressing the entire business in terms of `SphericalBesselJ[]` cures the problem:

```
NIntegrate[r With[{x = r BesselJZero[15/2, 1]}, 
                  Sqrt[2 x/π] SphericalBesselJ[7, x]]^2, {r, 0, 1/50}]
   1.1879560281974252*^-27
```

The nice thing about `SphericalBesselJ[]` is that it does not auto-evaluate to a potentially numerically unstable combination of trigonometric functions, unlike `BesselJ[15/2, x]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just another story of precision. For the first sample:

```
a = 2/100;
NIntegrate[BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1] r]^2 r, {r, 0, a}, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
N[Integrate[BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1] r]^2 r, {r, 0, a}], 40]
(* Let's check the difference between the above two result *)
%% - %
```

> ```
> 1.187956028197538867114723184727333535080*10^-27
> 1.187956028197538867114723184727562859206*10^-27
> -2.29324126*10^-58
> ```

For the second sample:

```
int2 = Integrate[BesselJ[15/2, 10^-7 r]^2 r, {r, 0, a}];
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 290}, N[int2, 16]]
```

> ```
> 1.194601120645255*10^-148
> ```

To summarize, one should always keep the precision issue in mind when facing numerical calculation.

Comment: It is not simply an working precision precision issue -- [J.M.'s answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117880/34008) and [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117908/34008) in a related discussion also started by you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    f = Interpolation[
  Table[{r, 10^12 BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1]*r]}, {r, 0, 0.02,
     0.0005}]];
```

and then integrate:

```
    10^-12*(NIntegrate[f[r], {r, 0, 0.02}] // Chop)

(*   1.67209*10^-14   *)
```

Have fun!

**Later edit**:  to address the comment of xzczd:
I, indeed, missed the square in my integration.
If one adds this square and looks at the plot:

```
Plot[BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1]^2*r], {r, 0, 0.02}]
```

one can see the following:

[image: plot]

It is easy to roughly estimate "by eye" the area under the curve as a fraction (by eye it is about 1/3) of the maximal height (0.00025), times the interval in which the curve is (visibly) different from zero (about 0.01):

```
 0.00025*0.01/3

(*  8.33333*10^-7   *)
```

yielding about `10^-6`.

If one applies the approach I proposed above (with the function squared that I missed):

```
 f = Interpolation[
   Table[{r, 10^12 BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1]^2*r]}, {r, 0, 0.02, 0.0005}]];

10^-12*(NIntegrate[f[r], {r, 0, 0.02}] // Chop)
```

one gets:

```
(*   1.40079*10^-6   *)
```

in agreement with the above estimate, rather than `10^-27` or `10^-148`.

Note that it is not necessary to multiply-divide by `10^12`. This is simply one of the traces of my earlier trials to force Mathematica to integrate properly without tricks.

Finally, I think there is some problem with this integration, when it is being done without any trick. When one looks at the plot above, one sees that the function is smooth, non/oscillating, non-diverging in the interval of interest, and, therefore, there should be no problem to integrate it numerically directly. Mathematica should be able to take care about precision automatically, as it, indeed, does in other comparable cases. The integration MUST work without any trick. I guess that the bug (if any) is somewhere in the Bessel function, rather than in the integration itself.
The workaround, however, seems to work properly.

Have fun still!

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this isn't the integrand OP struggling with…

Comment: @xzczd Please have a look at the later edit.

Comment: You misread OP's expression again, it should be `BesselJ[15/2, BesselJZero[15/2, 1] r]^2 r` 囧