# Why NIntegrate is badly-behaved on $J_{\frac{9}{2}}(x)$ by default?

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy, implementation-details

A friend of mine showed me this example:

```
Plot[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["The integrand seems to be simple", 14]]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}] // N
(* 0.000148473 <- This is the correct result *)

NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}]
(*-1.26625*10^170 *)
```

It's not hard to fix the code:

```
(* Solution 1 *)
NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
(* 0.0001484729674125616 *)

(* Solution 2 *)
Clear@f
f[x_?NumericQ] := BesselJ[9/2, x]
NIntegrate[f@x, {x, 0, 1}]
(* 0.000148473 *)
```

But I wonder **why** `NIntegrate` fails in such a wild way by default?

Seeing the *Solution 2* above, it's natural to guess that `NIntegrate` has done some improper symbolic processing, but this seems not to be true:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
(* -1.26625*10^170 *)
```

Comment: `NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LobattoKronrodRule"]` gives better approximation

Comment: Just as I noted [in another thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117880), an expression in terms of `SphericalBesselJ[]` that *Mathematica* does not auto-expand to its trigonometric form will give better results: `NIntegrate[Sqrt[2 x/π] SphericalBesselJ[4, x], {x, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `NIntegrate` evaluates the integrands before starting the actual 
integration, in some cases (like this one) it is better to define the integrand function `F` with the signature `F[x_?NumericQ]`.

```
BF[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := BesselJ[n, x]

NIntegrate[BF[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}]

(* 0.000148473 *)

Integrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 1}]
%% // N

(* Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] (30 Cos[1] + 
   Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] FresnelS[Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]] - 20 Sin[1]) *)

(* 0.000148473 *)
```

When expanded

```
BesselJ[9/2, x] // Expand

(* -((105 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Cos[x])/x^(7/2)) + (
 10 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Cos[x])/x^(3/2) + (105 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sin[x])/x^(
 9/2) - (45 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sin[x])/x^(5/2) + (
 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sin[x])/Sqrt[x] *)
```

the oscillatory nature of the integrand terms near zero confuses `NIntegrate`'s algorithms.

(I have answered very similar questions in different forums over the years.)

A similar discussion/answer is J.M.'s answer of ["NIntegrate and Integrate of a Spherical Bessel function"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117880/34008).

And as J.M. noted in a comment :

> "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 does absolutely nothing because BesselJ[] is
>   already auto-expanded in the half-integer case, and the resulting
>   expression is numerically iffy.

(We mention this because of the attempt to remedy the situation with "SymbolicProcessing" in the question.)

Comment: As an addendum: `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` does absolutely nothing because `BesselJ[]` is already auto-expanded in the half-integer case, and the resulting expression is numerically iffy.

Comment: @J.M. I should say I'm a little surprising, I didn't notice that `NIntegrate` evaluates its first argument while it owns `HoldAll` attribute, well, does `NIntegrate` always evaluate its first argument? (Maybe I should start a new question?) BTW @anton the `// Expand` is redundant :)

Comment: I think, @xzczd, that the way to answer that would involve the `IntegrationMonitor` framework that Anton introduced to us previously. Which would be an interesting separate question, I would say.

Comment: @j.m OK, I started [a new question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117994/1871).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make it a comment and then can't control the words. I think the problem is arising from the fact that the value of the function and its derivative is too small to near `x=0`.

```
Plot[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, .01}] 
Plot[Evaluate[D[BesselJ[9/2, x], x]], {x, 0, 0.01}]
```

[image]

As you can see the derivative is highly oscillatory at this small range.

When you are using `Integrate` it is doing a symbolic evaluation which keeps this violent things out of the picture. When you are going with `NIntegrate`, each point counts and so does their errors.

One way to avoid this is, as you already suggested, is to increase `WorkingPrecision`. Another way could be starting from a finite `x`, for example,

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 10^-4, 1}]
```

> 0.000146199

Just for the record, at small `x` `Integrate` can also behave weired.

```
Integrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0, 10^-4}] // N
```

> -0.000048699

```
Integrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 0., 10^-4}] // N
```

> 0.

just by changing `0` to `0.`