# NIntegrate evaluates its 1st argument while it has the attribute HoldAll?

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, implementation-details

`NIntegrate` owns the attribute `HoldAll`:

```
Attributes@NIntegrate
(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

However, when reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117908/1871), I surprisingly noticed that at least in the following case the 1st argument of `NIntegrate` is actually evaluated!:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[9/2, x], {x, 1, 2}] // Trace
```

[image]

So my question is, does `NIntegrate` **always** evaluates its 1st argument? If the answer is Yes, what's the meaning of this design, why not simply use `HoldRest`?

Comment: Another example: `NIntegrate[LegendreP[9, x], {x, 0, 1}] // Trace`. I don't have time to write a detailed answer at the moment, but as I noted, the `IntegrationMonitor` framework might be revealing (maybe Anton will write an answer if he sees this).

Comment: @J.M. After some more testing, I found the phenomenon seems to be quite general, a not-that-outstanding but simpler example: `NIntegrate[x + x, {x, 0, 1}] // Trace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the observed behavior is in full accord with the `HoldAll` attribute, just check what happens when there is no such attribute:

```
nIntegrate[x + x, {x, 1, 2}] // Trace
```

> ```
> {{x + x, 2 x}, nIntegrate[2 x, {x, 1, 2}]}
> ```

From the above it is seen that the arguments are evaluated **before** applying the rules associated with the function `nIntegrate`. The purpose of the `HoldAll` attribute is to prevent evaluation of the arguments before applying the rules, and this is exactly what happens in the case of `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[x + x, {x, 1, 2}] // Trace
```

> ```
> {NIntegrate[x + x, {x, 1, 2}], {x + x, 
>   2 x}, {{x} =., {x =.}, {x =., Null}, {Null}}, {x =., Null}, 3.}
> ```

Comment: I think now I understand the meaning of this design, if `NIntegrate` just owns `HoldRest`, something like `x = 0; NIntegrate[x + x, {x, 1, 2}]` won't give the desired result, but then another question comes to my mind: why `*Plot/*Plot3D` isn't designed to be like this? If so, there won't be any "Why `Plot[D[x, x], {x, 0, 1}]` doesn't work?" question!… well, maybe I should once again start a new question?

Comment: @xzczd Actually `Plot` and `Plot3D` also work the same way: they do have the `HoldAll` attribute but in version 10 somehow it is not listed when you evaluate `Plot // Attributes` (in previous versions it was listed). You can receive direct evidence that the attribute does work by evaluating `Trace[Plot[x + x, {x, 0, 2}]][[;; 2]]`. As to "Why `Plot[D[x, x], {x, 0, 1}]` doesn't work?", it is easy to understand it you remember that `Plot` localizes variables like `Block` (read the first point under the "Details and Options" section!). So with `Block[{x = 1}, D[x, x]]` you get exactly the same!

Comment: No, they're not same, as mentioned by Marius Ladegård Meyer in the answer above: "`NIntegrate` first localizes the values of all variables, **then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic**, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically." If `*Plot/*Plot3D` works like this, then `D[x, x]` will become `1` before the numeric value is plugged in.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, but these details aren't from the `HoldAll` attribute: it is internal working of these functions. Actually `Plot` also evaluates `f` with variables being symbolic as you can see from `f[x_Symbol] := Print["symbolic evaluation!"]; f[x_Real] := x; Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}];`.

Comment: @xzczd You can force `Plot` to work like `NIntegrate` using undocumented option `Evaluated -> True`: `Plot[D[x, x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]`.

Answer (score 5):

From the "Details and Options" section in the docs:

> NIntegrate first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates
>   f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the
>   result numerically.

So I guess this is expected behavior.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked the document more carefully!