# Function not being evaluated inside NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I am trying to integrate the difference in a stepwise function and a continuous function, but the value I am getting is as if the step-wise function were identically zero, which I know it is not. Here is my code

```
NumLessThan[x_, data_] := (i = 1; 
  For[i := 1, x > Sort[data][[i]] && i <= Length[data], ,If[++i > Length[data], Break[]]]; i - 1)    
CDFDisc[x_, data_] := NumLessThan[x, Sort[data]]/Length[data]

data = 
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 
  2]; Plot[{CDF[NormalDistribution[], x], CDFDisc[x, data]}, {x, -5, 
  4}]

NIntegrate[
 Abs[CDF[NormalDistribution[], x] - CDFDisc[x, data]], {x, -10, 10}]
(* 10. *)

Plot[
 Abs[CDF[NormalDistribution[], x] - CDFDisc[x, data]], {x, -10,
   10}, PlotRange -> Full]

NIntegrate[CDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -10, 10}]
(* 10. *)
```

I am aware that my discrete CDF function is algorithmically terrible, but I am just trying to get it to work before I make it computationally more optimal. The function `CDFDisc` outputs the correct values. And when I plot the integrand, I get exactly what I would expect. The mystery is why, inside `NIntegrate` it is treating `CDFDisc` as if it were zero everywhere.

Comment: I think you are looking for `CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x]`

Comment: Cool, of course Mathematica has a built in function for this. Thank you. Do you have any ideas why what I did breaks though? For some reason `NIntegrate` thinks my `CDFDisc` is zero, and I can't figure out why. In addition to getting this specific example working I want to get an understanding of how what I did is wrong.

Comment: Because *Mathematica* it's trying to be clever and solve the integral analytically first. Use `x_?NumericQ` to force a numerical only interpretation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your last comment just clarified a lot about how Mathematica works, and cleared up a lot of frustration/confusion.

Comment: While the underlying principal might be the same, had I read that question before reading your answer to mine, I would not have realized they were related. Just saying, having them both online might provide future value to confused noobs like myself.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Posts marked as duplicate won't be removed, they'll exist as root signs (and kind of supplement), so don't worry :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10397/rhermans) has already suggested a better way for coding `CDFDisc`, here I'll just explain why your `CDFDisc` seems to be zero. It's because:

1. Though `NIntegrate` has the attribute `HoldAll`, it symbolically evaluates its integrand before integrates it. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117994/1871) for more information.
2. `CDFDisc[x, data]` evaluates to `0` as long as `x` is a symbol.

So, once again, a straightforward way to fix your code is adding `_?NumericQ` to `CDFDisc`:

```
CDFDisc // Clear
CDFDisc[x_?NumericQ, data_] := ……
```

BTW the following is another way to define `CDFDisc`:

```
CDFDisc[x_] = 
 Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
  Piecewise[{Range@Length@data/Length@data, x > # & /@ Sort[data]}\[Transpose] // 
    Reverse]
```

Comment: Figuring out how your `CDFDisc` function works has taught me so much about MMA. Thank you. The part I still don't understand is the `Simplify\`PWToUnitStep@` at the beginning, as I can't find PWToUnitStep in any documentation, although it is clear I think what the effect is.

Comment: @irh Yeah it's not documented but as you've noticed its usage is pellucid and is briefly introduced in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133530/1871). It's actually not necessary for defining `CDFDisc`, I add it because piecewise function defined with `UnitStep` is usually more efficient and convenient for numeric calculation. This function is also used in dozens of posts in this site, you may have a look: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simplify%5C%60PWToUnitStep