# Evaluation of a hypergeometric function

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I am working with functions like

```
f[z_] = Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z]
```

Here is a plot of this function over the interval $z \in [0,1]$:

[image: plot of the function in the interval (0,1)]

```
Plot[f[z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

As you can see, Mathematica has difficulties evaluating it in the region $z \approx 0$. This is surprising, because the hypergeometric function admits by definition a simple series expansion around $z = 0$,
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{7!}{(3!)^2} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)} z^n = 1 + 2 z + \frac{25}{9} z^2 + \ldots
$$

The problem is that Mathematica does not use this defining property of the hypergeometric function, but instead it "simplifies" it to

```
f[z] = (140*(-60*z + 60*z^2 - 11*z^3 - 60*Log[1 - z] + 90*z*Log[1 - z] - 36*z^2*Log[1 - z] + 3*z^3*Log[1 - z]))/(3*z^7)
```

and it turns out that cancellations between large numbers occur in this expression when $z \approx 0$.

How can I instruct mathematica to not perform this "simplification" in general? Is there a way I can use the command Hold or something similar?

What I want to do eventually is evaluate numerically some integrals in which $f(z)$ appears in the integrand, so I need a robust way of evaluating the function over the interval $z \in [0,1]$.

Comment: The symbolic calculation can be stopped by `f[z_] := Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z]
` or more strictly `Clear[f]; f[z_?NumericQ] := Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z]`, but these solutions may not be suitable for the real problem. I think it's better to make the question more specific e.g. show an integral you want to calculate. (The integral should be simplified as much as possible of course. ) BTW somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117888/1871

Comment: Your function can be expressed in terms of the [Legendre function of the second kind](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreQGeneral/26/01/01/0006/). You could try reformulating in terms of `LegendreQ[]`.

Comment: @J.M., the Legendre functions get auto-expanded in the same way: the relevant one here is `LegendreQ[3, 1 - 2/z]`, which automatically becomes $-\frac{10}{x^2}+\frac{\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right) \left(x^2-10 x+10\right)
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(2-\frac{2}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)}{x^2}+\frac{10}{x}-\frac{11}{6}$ upon evaluation and then has the same numerical issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands

```
Plot[Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z], {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

or/and

```
f[z_] = Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z]; Plot[f[z], {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

do the job.

Addition.

```
Integrate[Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

> $\frac{133}{9} $

```
NIntegrate[Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z], {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

> $14.7777777777777 $

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but it might be worth checking out.

```
f[z_] = Hypergeometric2F1[4, 4, 8, z] // FunctionExpand
(*(140 (-(11 z^3) + 3 z^3 Log[1 - z] + 60 z^2 - 36 z^2 Log[1 - z] - 
   60 z + 90 z Log[1 - z] - 60 Log[1 - z]))/(3 z^7)*)

<< PrecisionPlot`

PrecisionPlot[f[z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

You can get `PrecisionPlot` from
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/715/

The problem seems to be precision rather than the function Mathematica uses.
Compare:

```
f[1/1000] // N
(*2.47395*10^8*)
```

with

```
f[1/1000] // N[#, 50] &
(*1.0020027811148271960352800702800453256995763414200*)
```

and while `f[0]` doesn't work, the limit does.

```
Limit[f[z], z -> 0]
(*1*)
```

Although PrecisionPlot is smoother, it doesn't really do a great job of matching the very small values of `z`.

Comment: `PrecisionPlot[]` was useful back in the day when `Plot[]` did not have the `WorkingPrecision` option; nowadays, the built-in function is adequate.